# R: two data frame merge with 2 variables and several other conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I am a beginner in R. Here is an example of a datatable (C) that I created using jmp. I have joined Table A and B  using A1 and B;C columns to create C . In the datatable B, the cloumn OP that contains CLO is dropped during the join while the column J from datatable A is updated during the join.
 I am trying to create the dataframe C using the merge command in R. I used the following expression:
 `C <- merge(B,A, BY=c("A1","B;C"),all.x = TRUE)` but I don't seem to get the Data frame C. I would appreciate any help from the community to solve this.

Data Frame A

```
A1    |  B;C | D |E |F  |G  | H |    I       |J  |K   |L   | M |
------|------|---|--|---|---|---|------------|---|----|----|---|
ABCD  |SD;TH |HO |2 |FA |   |ENG| 201808:SPR |54 |PRO |VAC |MAA|
JCBW  |RF;TH |HO |2 |FU |VIN|FUT| 504278:SPR |4  |PRO |VAC |MAA|
TVGH  |ED;UJ |HO |2 |FU |VIN|FUT| 504276:SPR |4  |PRO |VAC |MAA|
IGHE  |WR;RE |HO |3 |IN |   |SPE| 504278:SPR |73 |PRO |VAC |MAA|
UUUU  |DF;TH |HO |3 |FU |   |FUT| 357193:IT  |13 |INT |VAC |MAA|
JFLD  |YO;TH |HO |3 |CH |BRI|CHE| 476306:SPR |6  |PRO |VAC |MAA|
|
```

Data frame B

```
OWN|COM|OP |GR |J | A1  | B;C | D|E |F |G  |H  |  I        |K  |L  |M
---|---|---|---|--|-----|-----|--|--|--|---|---|-----------|---|---|----
SUP|X  |CLO|ARE|16|59HUW|BB;TH|HO|8 |FA|MIC|SPE|90278:SPR  |INT|VAC|MAA
SUP|X  |OPE|ARE|75|ABCD |SD;TH|HO|8 |FU|MIC|ENG|201808:SPR |INT|VAC|MAA
SUP|X  |CLO|ARE|4 |59HVG|BB;RE|HO|8 |FA|MIC|SPE|6074278:SPR|INT|VAC|MAA
PAD|X  |CLO|PEN|30|9RHSG|BV;TH|HO|2 |FA|   |SPE|201808:SPR |PRO|VAC|MAA
PAD|X  |OPE|PEN|99|UUUU |DF;TH|HO|8 |FU|MIC|FUT|357193:IT  |PRO|VAC|MAA
PAD|X  |OPE|PEN|65|IGHE |WR;RE|HO|8 |IN|   |SPE|504278:SPR |PRO|VAC|MAA
PAD|X  |CLO|PEN|13|S9K7E|FN;TH|HO|8 |FA|MIC|FUT|394290:SPR |PRO|VAC|MAA
```

Data frame C

```
OWN|COM|OP |GR |J  |A1  | B;C |D |E |F | G |H  |    I     | K |L  |M
---|---|---|---|---|----|-----|--|--|--|---|---|----------|---|---|----
SUP|x  |OPE|ARE|99 |ABCD|SD;TH|HO|8 |FU|MIC|ENG|201808:SPR|INT|VAC|MAA
PAD|x  |OPE|PEN|120|UUUU|DF;TH|HO|8 |FU|MIC|FUT|357193:IT |PRO|VAC|MAA
PAD|x  |OPE|PEN|73 |IGHE|WR;RE|HO|8 |IN|   |SPE|504278:SPR|PRO|VAC|MAA
   |   |   |   |4  |JCBW|RF;TH|HO|2 |FU|VIN|FUT|504278:SPR|PRO|VAC|MAA
   |   |   |   |25 |TVGH|ED;UJ|HO|2 |FU|VIN|FUT|504276:SPR|PRO|VAC|MAA
   |   |   |   |15 |JFLD|YO;TH|HO|3 |CH|BRI|CHE|476306:SPR|PRO|VAC|MAA
```

Comment: Realizing this is your first post...it will hep if you provide data in a way that can be imported into R for folks to try and test working solutions. Output of the `dput(df)` will do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: Have a look at this [relevant post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)